# ffmpeg showwaves color

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to produce a video that has a lime green colored waveform overlayed on top of a background image. Unfortunately though, there is a grey color in the lines as you can see here:

[image: See image here]

How can I make the grey parts lime green as well?

And if possible, I would like to make the lines thicker as well.

Here is my ffmpeg command:

`ffmpeg -i input.aac -i background.jpg -filter_complex "[0:a]aformat=sample_fmts=s16:sample_rates=4410:channel_layouts=mono,showwaves=size=300x200:mode=p2p:rate=10:colors=#68b847[fg];[1:v][fg]overlay=130:150,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -r 10 -c:a copy -r 10 -movflags +faststart output.mp4`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

ffmpeg -i input.aac -i background.jpg -filter_complex "[0:a]aformat=channel_layouts=mono,showwaves=s=1920x1080:mode=p2p:r=30:colors=#68b847[v];[1:v][v]overlay=format=auto:x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2,format=yuv420p[outv]" -map "[outv]" -map 0:a -c:v libvpx-vp9 -c:a copy -shortest output.mp4